# Blue creepers? Does anyone know why?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

All my creepers are blue for some reason.  All the other mobs are okay in color except creepers every creeper is dark blue completely why?

Comment: Photo please...?

Comment: Do you have any resource packs or mods active?

Comment: o i dont. just blue creepers

Answer (score 4):

In the vanilla game, charged creepers have a blue "sparkling" outline. Charged creepers are formed when lightning hits near a normal creeper. This is usually a rare occurence, but you may see more than one during a lightning storm considering creepers spawn in mobs and creepers in a radius of 3 to 4 from a lightning strike are converted.

Other than that, you could just be seeing a graphical glitch or have an (outdated) resource pack override your creepers skin.

Comment: thanks. alooooot  ii havent been letting  my game update so i just did and everything is better!

Answer (score 1):

There are blue creepers (dubbed "[Mana Creepers](http://am2.wikia.com/wiki/Mana_Creeper)") from the Ars Magica 2 mod.

[image: Definitely blue...]

*It's definitely blue.*